# The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe error

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-extensions

I have been trying to use remote explorer in vscode and connect to the ssh but i'm facing this error. It says no such hostbut i don't know how to learn the name of the host. It is a simple problem but i can't solve it, please help.

```
[18:53:45.485] Log Level: 2
[18:53:45.488] remote-ssh@0.65.8
[18:53:45.488] win32 x64
[18:53:45.490] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+test", attempt 1
[18:53:45.490] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[18:53:45.491] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[18:53:45.491] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[18:53:45.491] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[18:53:45.492] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[18:53:45.492] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[18:53:45.492] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[18:53:45.492] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[18:53:45.493] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[18:53:45.493] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[18:53:45.493] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[18:53:45.493] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[18:53:45.494] SSH Resolver called for host: test
[18:53:45.494] Setting up SSH remote "test"
[18:53:45.519] Using commit id "6cba118ac49a1b88332f312a8f67186f7f3c1643" and quality "stable" for server
[18:53:45.524] Install and start server if needed
[18:53:48.543] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[18:53:48.593] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
[18:53:48.593] > p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[18:53:48.599] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 50863 test bash
[18:53:48.603] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[18:53:48.831] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[18:53:48.831] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[18:53:51.124] > ssh: Could not resolve hostname test: No such host is known. 
[18:53:51.135] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[18:53:52.412] "install" terminal command done
[18:53:52.413] Install terminal quit with output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[18:53:52.413] Received install output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[18:53:52.414] Resolver error: Error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
    at Function.Offline (c:\Users\90543\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:397092)
    at c:\Users\90543\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:394642
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\90543\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:395020)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\90543\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:489314)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\90543\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:453110
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\90543\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:456460)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\90543\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:454189)
    at async c:\Users\90543\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:526942
```